# Speculative application by mail after not receiving answers by e‑mail… Is it still relevant for small companies?

Tags: job-search, united-states, technology, france, apprentice

### My case :

I’m in the process of searching an apprenticeship in the south of the United States for my French’s (not mainland) master degree [with my wage reimbursed up to the minimal French wage by my state. So for the company that would hire me, it would be indeed an at least year long “work for free plan” in practice](https://www.expert-comptable-tpe.fr/articles/remboursement-formation-et-salaires-par-opca/) (with most of the year spent learning in college in Guadeloupe instead of the United States in terms of visa).
[In addition to this, there’s a 8000€ state employment bonus as part of the recovery plan, for any companies signing an apprenticeship agreement for an apprentice aged above 18](https://travail-emploi.gouv.fr/formation-professionnelle/entreprise-et-alternance/aide-exceptionnelle-apprentissage) (under the [esef legal status](https://www.net-entreprises.fr/media/2017/01/formulaire_E0.pdf)).

Because of the required nature of the job agreement, I’m thinking my best luck is to try with small flexible companies as **[larger companies definitely won’t accept the required schedule](http://ytrezq.sdfeu.org/candidature/required%20schedule.pdf)**. Those typically having a low revenue but who don’t take apprentices normally. Especially those who looked for a part‑time position in my field recently *(please correct me if I’m wrong on this assumption compared to alternatives)*.
Legally speaking, besides what I’m describing in the applications I send, the [ᴄɴꜰᴇ is here to help a would be employer](https://www.foreign-companies.urssaf.eu/index.php/en/).

**More generally, [I exhausted all apprentice job offers, leaving only unsolicited applications and in the case in Guadeloupe, I even exhausted all possible unsolicited applications for the remaining companies not on strike](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/182148)**. I don’t know if this might be different, but after all it was through inefficient unsolicited applications, I had my last 3 required internships.

### Question :

I know the best way is to apply using their specified ways of applying if any or to use their contact forms. But I came up to build a long list of companies that didn’t send a reply for months. **Most of the time, when I call them, it appears my e‑mails went completely unnoticed because of their spam flow**.
In that case, and in order to better attract attention, **would it be a good idea to try again by physical mail** ? Or would I make the wrong impression because it would be considered an outdated technology ? Especially since *I’m looking for an apprenticeship in IT.*
In the latter case, should I instead send many e‑mails with the hope to that time get one of them noticed ?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133292/discussion-on-question-by-user2284570-speculative-application-by-mail-after-not).

Answer (score 3):

**Speculative application by mail after not receiving answers by e‑mail… Is it still relevant for small companies?**

No. Unsolicited physical applications is just as effective as unsolicited email applications. Which is not effective at all.

You seem to be targeting small businesses. You're absolutely way better off targeting MNCs that have a presence in your country, as they are more well-equipped to offer your employment.

You can argue all your want about the various risks. But it doesn't matter. The perception of risk is all that matters. And HR experts at companies are going to simply block you if you get into an argument with them, as you have with multiple people here.

Just listing all the factors that are going against you:

- Small business: Has low risk tolerance
- Unsolicited: Unlikely to actually be hiring
- Foreign: They will need to hire their own experts

In your situation I would recommend you eliminate as many of those factors as possible.

Comment: **So do you mean there’s no difference between by e‑mail and physical mail ?** Any French here would be able to confirm the ᴄɴꜰᴇ would replace such experts concerning the French part of laws.

Comment: [Otherwise, they were already antivax unrest in Guadeloupe because the population is mostly against ᴄᴏᴠɪᴅ19 jab unlike the mainland](https://www.thestkittsnevisobserver.com/anti-vax-protests-several-police-injured-on-martinique-and-guadeloupe/) and the president just said he would put crap on the unvaxed (loosely translated as `pissed off`) which just blew away my hopes to find an apprenticeship on time through non unsolicited means… I [exhausted all job offers](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/182148)… But after all, it was using this way (cold call) I found my last 2 school internships…

Comment: @user2284570 You're continually missing the point. I don't care what experts you can find, or documentation you can find, or French nationals. I don't care about that stuff, and neither will employers. Why do you think employers owe it to you to bother to attempt to understand French law?

Comment: Because it is part of the common basic local French knowledge (the ᴜʀꜱᴀᴀꜰ) and that in the end, it might be simpler than taking someone in the ᴜꜱ ([like no payroll tax to care about](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payroll_tax)) ? And that there’s a lack of a better alternative ? **Otherwise, do you mean there’s no difference between by e‑mail and physical mail ?**

Comment: I mean, somebody in the USA is not going to care about what "basic local French knowledge" is. They don't have "basic local French knowledge". Why should an employer in the USA care about French laws.

Comment: [because they would end up being paid by the state for doing it](https://travail--emploi-gouv-fr.translate.goog/formation-professionnelle/entreprise-et-alternance/aide-exceptionnelle-apprentissage?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=fr&_x_tr_pto=wapp) ? (maybe twice considering I may perform valuable work). **Otherwise, do you mean there’s no difference between by e‑mail and physical mail for applying ?**

Comment: @user2284570 To know they would end up being paid, they would have to understand French laws to begin with. Offering companies money to employ you looks like a scam. So they would ask: "What's the catch. What are we missing?" They are not going to bother getting answers to those questions. If they NEED your valuable work, they likely are hiring.

Comment: In answering your question, both are mostly useless in your particular circumstance.

Comment: Then as I said, as a personal experience, I found my last 2 months internships through cold calling with companies not hiring (or in the case of the last 1 not advertising it yet).

Comment: Why not just trusting the ministry of labor website instead of seeking the specific temporary laws ? With the [schedule being sent with the application, the catch is pretty clear : it almost looks like a `came when you want plan` (except it’s not me but the college who is requiring me to not work)](http://ytrezq.sdfeu.org/candidature/required%20schedule.pdf). A simple [Google lookup is also giving results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22apprenticeship%22+france+8000%E2%82%AC).

Comment: **and mostly useless, but equal ?**

Comment: @user2284570 The most obvious reason is that information on a "ministry of labour" website is not legally binding. What matters is the law. When a small business owner has spent their entire lives building a company, they are not going to put all of that risk to hire someone they weren't even looking for, according to information that isn't legally binding, on a website written in a foreign language, from a department of a government they don't understand, recommended to them by a stranger that emailed them out of the blue.

Comment: "I found my last 2 months internships through cold calling with companies not hiring" Yes, and you can play Russian Roulette and think it's a perfectly safe game. I'm suggesting your time can be better spent, looking at more realistic options.

Comment: @user2284570 They are both mostly useless. Trying to differentiate between two things that are mostly useless is hard. You're going to get more noise than signal.

Comment: Problem is I explained it’s the most realistic option I’m having as I just can’t pay for working in mainland.